# THTTPRIO SSL using Client Certificate doesn't work as it should

Tags: web-services, delphi, ssl, soap

I have a SOAP webserver developed in Delphi XE2 that exposes some methods and it uses SSL. I built my client also in Delphi XE2, and I use THTTPRIO to connect to webserver. My question is related to the use of SSL certificatest with THTTPRIO. If I call my webservice it works without having a certificate installed, but I think that it shouldn't.

Second scenario :I have a self signed certificate which I installed it and after I made a call to my webservice it works also.

When I inspected my events: HTTPRIOAfterExecute and HTTPRIOBeforeExecute, I converted SoapRequest and SOAPResponse to string from TStream and seems that it isn't encrypted in both cases. I also found on another forum the same question but with no response.

I searched for info about SOAP SSL Clients with Delphi but couldn't find any new info. Could any of you  guys give me some advices regarding this issue?

Comment: `without having a certificate installed` - do you mean on the client side? Clients do not need to install the server certificate to access a HTTPS server, they need only the higher-level certificates in the chain.

Comment: hello, yes I mean on the client side, and I was reffering at a client certificate. On the server side I use TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL to load my server certificate from a .crt file.

Comment: I guess there are not many web services which require client certificates, with exceptions like banking and other high risk environments. It is more common that clients want to verify the server identity, and this is done with server certificates.

Comment: ok, I understand this, but if I call my webservice from a php client it requires a client certificate to make that call, otherwise I can't make that call. I think that my server should always request a client certificate in order to receive and resolve a request, but I don't know how to make this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I call my webservice it works without having a certificate
>   installed, but I think that it shouldn't.

Not many web services require client certificates (with exceptions like banking and other high risk environments). It is more common that clients want to verify the server identity, and this is done with server certificates.

So I would say this web service does work in a normal, expected way.

---

> HTTPRIOAfterExecute and HTTPRIOBeforeExecute, I converted SoapRequest
>   and SOAPResponse to string from TStream and seems that it isn't
>   encrypted in both cases

This is correct, the message payload will appear unencrypted because SSL / TLS does encryption on the transport layer. Your application will not see the encrypted data, which actually makes things easier.

You can add encryption for the message payload, there are generic libraries for this (however I have no experience with using encryption HTTPRio).

Comment: I have read a little bit more on how SSL works and you are right in your answer, I forgot that SSL does encryption on transport layer and not on application layer (my question regarding encrpted data in those events was a dumb one). What it seems strange to me is that with HTTPRIO you need to install the client certificate and then pass the serial number of the client certificate. In the end I will use RemObjects SDK to accomplish my task. Thanks alot for the info.